# Spring MongoDB - ProjectionOperation Question for multiple values

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a `DAOImpl` with an override function.  I'm trying to use an aggregation to first `filter` then `match` then to `project`.

```java
    public Map<Long, Integer> getUsersByAccount() {

        MatchOperation filterByAccountId = match(new Criteria(ACCOUNT_ID).nin(Arrays.asList(null, "")));
        GroupOperation groupByMasterAccount = group(DEFAULT_MASTER_ACCOUNT_ID).count().as("countOfFooUsers");
        ProjectionOperation projectByIDandCount = project()
                .and("_id")
                .as("defaultMasterAccountId");
        projectByIDandCount.and("countOfFooUsers");
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                filterByAccountId,
                groupByMasterAccount,
                projectByIDandCount
        );

        AggregationResults<MAandUsers> maUsersResult = mongoTemplate
                .aggregate(aggregation, USERS_COLLECTION, MAandUsers.class);
```

The inner class above `MAandUsers` within the `IMPL`:

```java
    @Data
    public static class MAandUsers {
        private Long defaultMasterAccountId;
        private Integer countOfFooUsers;
    }
```

However, my `maUsersResult`returns a `null` value for `countOfFooUsers` when, in my test case, there should be `1`.  I'm assuming my `projection` operation is off ---> `projectByIDandCount.and("countOfFooUsers");`

Is there a way for me to use spring's mongotemplate to receive back multiple values on projection operations?  I'm fairly new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using, [andInclude](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ProjectionOperation.html#andInclude(java.lang.String...))

```
ProjectionOperation projectByIDandCount = project()
    .and("_id").as("defaultMasterAccountId")
    .andInclude("countOfFooUsers");
```